# How to loop through two loops at the same time?

Tags: python, loops

I have two lists:

```
list_one = [3 5 3 5 3 5 5 5 3 3 5 3]
```

and

```
list_two = [[2000, 2100], [2200, 2300], [2500, 2600]]
```

I want to alter the first number in each sublist in `list_two` by a corresponding number from `list_one`, such that

```
list_two = [[(2100-3), 2100], [(2300-5), 2300], [(2600-3), 2600)]
```

I have the following code but it is doing this in the wrong order.

```
new_list = []
for i in list_two:
    for k in list_one:
        a = i[1]-k
        b = i[1]
        c = [a, b]
    new_list.append(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with list comprehension,

```
In [3]: list_two = [[2000, 2100], [2200, 2300], [2500, 2600]]                                                                                                                                               

In [4]: list_one = [3,5,3,5,3,5,5,5,3,3,5,3]                                                                                                                                                                

In [5]: [[i[0]-j, i[1]]for i,j in zip(list_two, list_one)]                                                                                                                                                  
Out[5]: [[1997, 2100], [2195, 2300], [2497, 2600]]
```